# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to open webgrind

Tags: apache, webgrind

I am using linux. I have installed webgrind for xdebug profiling of php code. I have made the proper changes in the httpd.conf etc.

when i am trying to connect from browser it says `500 Internal Server Error`

I cant figure it out.

```
      [Tue Feb 18 22:07:02 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/webapps/webgrind/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/) in Unknown on line 0
      [Tue Feb 18 22:07:02 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0
      [Tue Feb 18 22:07:02 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/usr/share/webapps/webgrind/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Look in your Apache error log. A 500 error should always be  detailed there.

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code means: there was an error but my configuration prevents me from giving the details; please find them in the log files.

Comment: updated the question with error_log

Comment: Look over [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=open_basedir+restriction+in+effect) for info on how to deal with the `open_basedir` restriction.

Comment: You're installing debuggers so I presume it's your own computer and not a shared hosting service. I suggest you simply remove `open_basedir` restrictions in your php.ini file.